# Lua pattern returns wrong match when fetching multiple substrings between brackets

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

So I have this problem with a regex. As seen below I use the regex"CreateRuntimeTxd%(.*%)"

```
local _code = [[
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    local dui = CreateDui("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", 1920, 1080)
    local duiHandle = GetDuiHandle(dui)
    CreateRuntimeTextureFromDuiHandle(CreateRuntimeTxd('rick'), 'nevergonnagiveuup', duiHandle)

    while true do
        Wait(0)
        DrawSprite('rick', 'nevergonnagiveuup', 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255)
    end
end)
]]

for match in string.gmatch(_code, "CreateRuntimeTxd%(.*%)") do
    print(match)
end
```

So the problem is that the current regex matches

```
CreateRuntimeTxd('rick'), 'nevergonnagiveuup', duiHandle)

    while true do
        Wait(0)
        DrawSprite('rick', 'nevergonnagiveuup', 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255)
    end
end)
```

but i only want it to match `CreateRuntimeTxd('rick')`

Comment: vanilla Lua does not support regular expressions. Lua's string patterns are less powerful. `.*` is a greedy match. anything after it in a pattern does not matter because `.*` will already match everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```lua
for match in string.gmatch(_code, "CreateRuntimeTxd%(.-%)") do
    print(match)
end
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/BrFpbL). *Details*:

- `CreateRuntimeTxd` - a literal text
- `%(` - a literal `(` char
- `.-` - zero or more characters (the least amount needed to complete a match)
- `%)` - a `)` char.

You may also use a negated character class, `[^()]*` (if there can be no `(` and `)` before `)`) or `[^)]*` (if `)` chars are still expected) instead of `.-`:

```lua
for match in string.gmatch(_code, "CreateRuntimeTxd%([^()]*%)") do
    print(match)
end
```

See [this Lua demo](https://ideone.com/LaWX6t).